# Recursive call untill error is No longer exist

Tags: r, recursion, try-catch

Recursively calling a function until the error is no longer an error at run time, i think i get the error because of a stack overflow,I have tried but not succeed end with **NULL or error**,any help,thanks.

```
fetchData <- function() 
    {
        #withRestarts(invokeRestart("a"),a=function(){QueryTrueFX()}) #i have tried restart within error function though i get NULL only
        qtf <- tryCatch(QueryTrueFX(),warning = function(w) {},error = function(e) {QueryTrueFX()})
        if(is.null(qtf))
        {
          fetchData()  
        }
    }
    a<-fetchData()
    Error in file(con, "r") : all connections are in use
    Called from: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
    Error during wrapup: all connections are in use
    Error during wrapup: target context is not on the stack
    a=tryCatch(fetchData(), error=function(e) NULL )
    a
    NULL
```

Comment: I have no idea what `QueryTrueFX` does, but from the error message I assume that file connections are not closed when you catch errors. Also, avoid recursion in R.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?  In all probability what you need is more along the lines of `(while !qtf) {sleep(10);your_function -> qtf; }`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I am continuously trying for a internet connection ,if it suddenly went down at run time.

Comment: How about `system('ping your_IP_address_here')`